# How to toggle between hide and view password Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passWordEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:password="true"/>
```

---

What should be done to toggle show/hide password in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Have you [googled](https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&ei=2ZoBWoWNNsLLwAK047fwBA&q=C%23+toggle+between+hide+and+view+password+Xamarin.Android&oq=C%23+toggle+between+hide+and+view+password+Xamarin.Android&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.452.452.0.848.1.1.0.0.0.0.151.151.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.150....0.CnsOEDhxTaE) it atleast once?

Comment: @L.Guthardt if somebody doesn't ask and somebody doesn't answer, google will not work. so please stop saying this stupid argument.

Comment: @cagri I agree with you, but not in this case. What OP asked about isn't something difficult. There are a bunch of ressources out there about this topic, even the docs would have solved this issue. So googling would have enlightened OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the InputType property of edittext and change it to show/hide. Take a look on the next code.

```
    bool isVisible;
    void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(isVisible)
            editText.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword;
        else
            editText.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;

        editText.SetSelection(editText.Text.Length);
        isVisible = !isVisible;
    }
```

Comment: It works for the first time but when I again press the button it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have the same code ? if you have the same code above should work

Comment: Thanks...This worked out perfectly...It was just a variable error.I had visible at one place and visibl at another.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) and set `passwordToggleEnabled` as `true`. It will automatically handle the toggle between show and hide password.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```